# five Threads working on a List of Tasks c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a List of URLs which I have to call and do some work on. This already works fine but the List is very large and execution takes very long.

I think I could speed up the programm by working on 5 Urls at the same time as a huge part of the executiontime is probaply the programm waiting for the Urls serverresponse.

I have a List of URLs

```
List<string> urls = getmyurls();
```

And then I'm iterating through them

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> result = dosomework(urls.ElementAt(i))
    urls.AddRange(result);
}
```

Sometimes I get some additional Urls returned which have to be processed too.

(Code is an example, my actual programm is structured a little bit diffrent. It's a minimal example to explain my problem.)

What I want is five threads running the function "dosomework" at the same time. Whenever one of them is finished I want it to start on the next URL.

Also: How many threads would you run?

Comment: Try searching. Parallel taks library.

Comment: If you want to go fast, abandon your simplistic idea that more threads = more speed. Learn how to do asynchronous IO rather than blocking IO.

Comment: As CodeCaster mentioned, TPL is a good place to start. It will determine for you how many tasks to run in parallel etc. And Parallel.For is very simple to put in

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx jump to parallel foreach

Comment: You definitely might want to have a look to the [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are attempting to resolve a URL and pull from the network, it's similar to pulling from the disk or reading from a database in that these are all I/O bound operations. Going parallel is actually not desirable as more threads doesn't help but rather hinder the performance. Your best bet is to utilize the `async` and `await` keywords, assuming you're on **.NET 4.5**.

Some people are suggesting `Parallel.ForEach` but this is best suited for CPU-bound tasks. For I/O bound tasks, you need `Task.WhenAll`.

[Here is great video demonstration](https://www.wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch/performing-i-o-bound-asynchronous-operations?videoId=performing-i-o-bound-asynchronous-operations) on Performing I/O-Bound Asynchronous Operations by Jeffrey Richter. I strongly encourage watching it. In the meantime, I would write your iterations calls like so.

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetUrls()
    {
        return new[] { "https://stackoverflow.com/", "http://www.google.com/" };
    }

    internal async Task Fetch()
    {
        var urls = GetUrls();
        var tasks = urls.Select(DoWorkAsync);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    internal Task DoWorkAsync(string url)
    {
        // TODO: Implement actual work on the URL in an async manner.
        return Task.FromResult(url);
    }
```

The idea being that you can get the URL's, and from each of the URL's select a task that executes on `DoWorkAsync`. All of these are then awaited.

**Update**

It appears as though throttling has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks).

Comment: But how do I know (or influence) how many Urls are called at the same time. It looks like the programm is calling all the urls as soon as possible.

Comment: That is a different question, I answered the original.  I would imagine if the list is potentially huge, you could implement some sort of buffer or queue and then batch calls out to N per time.

Comment: Thats the original problem. The List is very huge. More than a 1000 Urls initally and each task could potentially add a few more.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. Even though I didn't have time to try it out. Thank you

Comment: I believe async + TPL Dataflow are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge fan of the [TPL Dataflow library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). It totally fits this use case and worth to be learnt.

Here is a raw implementation to show you a bit how it works.

```
var processURL = new TransformManyBlock<string, string>(url => {
    return dosomework(url);
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

var urls = getmyurls();
foreach(var url in urls)
    processURL.Post(url);

processURL.Completion.Wait();
var results = processURL.Receive();
```

A nice example of process pipeline can be read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is probably Parallel LINQ.

Consider the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd460714(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:
As it comes to running on multiple threads you add `WithDegreeOfParallelism(6)` where 6 is "thread" count. This not exactly 6 thread but is what you want :)
Here you have a nice explanation: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx

Also
`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` specifies maximum level of parallelism

Comment: But would'nt that execute all my Urls at once. How can I determine how many parrellel threads are allowed at once?

Comment: " I think I could speed up the programm by working on 5 Urls at the same time "

I understood this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Maybe I dont understand it completly. I want to execute my functions for all Urls but only 5 at a time. Whenever I'm done with one I want to start on the next.

Comment: Ok, assuming you have some actual CPU-bound tasks to do with these links what I wrote may actually help you. Consider this example:
Lets say you have big list of numbers and you want to calculate sqrt for everyone. You can do this `var querySequential = (from item in test2 select Math.Sqrt(item)).ToArray()`.
To make it paralell just change it to: `var queryParallel = (from item
in test2.AsParallel().AsOrdered().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5) select Math.Sqrt(item)).ToArray()`
I've checked it, and parallel is about 3 times faster then sequential so it works :) Of course is calculated 5 at a time

Comment: Thank you, this is really intressting and will most definitly try this out, but in this specially case I have the problem that the results of the tasks might add additional tasks to the queue. That will be hard to incorporate here.