# Throttling HttpClient requests by some variable

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore, dotnet-httpclient, throttling

I'm writing a class that uses HttpClient to access an API and I want to throttle the number of concurrent calls that can be made to a certain function in this class. The trick is though that the limit is per tenant and multiple tenants might be using their own instance of the class at a time.

My Tenant class is just a container for read-only context information.

```
public class Tenant
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string ApiKey { get; }
}
```

Here's the ApiClient:

```
public class ApiClient
{
    private readonly Tenant tenant;

    public ApiClient(Tenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public async Task<string> DoSomething()
    {
        var response = await this.SendCoreAsync();
        return response.ToString();
    }

    private Task<XElement> SendCore()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpRequest = this.BuildHttpRequest();
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
            return XElement.Parse(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is throttle the `SendCore` method and limit it to two concurrent requests **per tenant**. I've read suggestions of using `TPL` or `SemaphoreSlim` to do basic throttling (such as here: [Throttling asynchronous tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks)), but I'm not clear on how to add in the further complication of the tenant.

Thanks for the suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I've attempted to use a set of `SemaphoreSlim` objects (one per tenant) contained in a `ConcurrentDictionary`. This seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is ideal. The new code is:

```
public class ApiClient
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> Semaphores = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
    private readonly Tenant tenant;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore;

    public ApiClient(Tenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
        this.semaphore = Semaphores.GetOrAdd(this.tenant.Name, k => new SemaphoreSlim(2));
    }

    public async Task<string> DoSomething()
    {
        var response = await this.SendCoreAsync);
        return response.ToString();
    }

    private Task<XElement> SendCore()
    {
        await this.semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var httpRequest = this.BuildHttpRequest();
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
                return XElement.Parse(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `Tenant`? Is it a class from some library (which one?) or your custom class? Would it make sense to modify it just for this purpose? Also, can one `Tenant` have more than one `ApiClient`?

Comment: Tenant is just a small context class that contains the name of the tenant and some connection information used by the API client like username/password. I'm using the ASP.NET WebJobs SDK and Tenant is simply injected in when I handle a service bus message. You can think of the Tenant object as read-only.

Comment: I've updated the question with a Semaphore approach I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SemaphoreSlim` approach seems mostly reasonable to me.

One potential issue is that if `Tenant`s can come and go over the lifetime of the application, then you'll be keeping semaphores even for `Tenant`s that don't exist anymore.

A solution to that would be to use [`ConditionalWeakTable<Tenant, SemaphoreSlim>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of your `ConcurrentDictionary`, which makes sure its keys can be garbage collected and when they are, it releases the value.

Comment: Thanks for this. Tenants are rarely removed from the system. Much less frequently than the service is restarted, so I think I'm safe.