# C# DB query app causes the DB server to stop responding: What tools can I use on the DB server to identify and study the choke point?

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I wrote a program modeled after the accepted answer for [Throttling asynchronous tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks). See code below. My program is essentially an ad-hoc DB "text search" tool. It runs on a Win 7 client machine. The program composes a large collection of `SELECT` statements (hundreds to thousands of them) and sends them to a remote DB server (The Win 7 client and the DB server are on the same A.D. domain. The DB server searched is only ever the `read-only` `secondary` server in an `Always On Availability Group`). Each invocation of the `Download` method creates 1-to-many `SELECT` queries (one SELECT per table column being searched) for one DB table. The `Download` method is invoked 1-to-thousands of times (once per table being searched).

`TPL Dataflow` works good so long as I limit the search to no more that 60-70 tables. More than that and it chokes (I think) the `SQL Server Database` and/or the DB server machine. I've played with various `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and `BoundedCapacity` values in attempt to control the client. With `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8` (the number of processors on my client machine, I can see that CPU and DISK peg on the DB server machine. With `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` and `BoundedCapacity = 1`, The CPU and DISK are ok on the DB server machine, but in the act of submitting the queries, my database read code:

```
SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
dataTable_TableDataFromFieldQuery.Load(sqlDataReader);
```

eventually throws an exception `"server has become unresponsive"`

What tools can I use on the DB server to identify the choke point? Even assuming that I need to improves my queries, what do I look for and where?

**Code from the other S.O. question modified for my use**

```
var downloader = new TransformBlock<string, DataTable>(tableName => Download(tableName), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism={various values 1-5, BoundedCapacity={various values 1-5} } );

var buffer = new BufferBlock<DataTable>();
downloader.LinkTo(buffer);

foreach(var tableName in tableNames)
    await downloader.SendAsync(tableName);

downloader.Complete();
await downloader.Completion;

IList<DataTable> responses;

if (buffer.TryReceiveAll(out responses))
{
    //process all DataTables
}
```

Comment: as @TheGeneral have suggested, you could use SQL Profiler to tap on what are the failing queries. However, i'd go with the necessity doing `foreach` and throwing that many queries to the server... yes, that `await downloader.SendAsync(tableName);`.. it might be light on the app, but you kill the db..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bit of a mess, I'm not sure if you know about these tools but i think you should become very familiar with them.

The first is the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler)

> Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL
>   Trace for monitoring an instance of the Database Engine or Analysis
>   Services. You can capture and save data about each event to a file or
>   table to analyze later. For example, you can monitor a production
>   environment to see which stored procedures are affecting performance
>   by executing too slowly

And the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/database-engine-tuning-advisor)

> The Microsoft Database Engine Tuning Advisor (DTA) analyzes databases
>   and makes recommendations that you can use to optimize query
>   performance. You can use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to select
>   and create an optimal set of indexes, indexed views, or table
>   partitions without having an expert understanding of the database
>   structure or the internals of SQL Server

The *Profiler*, if used strategically should be able to help narrow down the problem. The *Tuning Adivsor* should be able to loosely aid in writing better queries.

Though without knowing exactly what you are doing and why it would be hard to give you a better answer. However, my gut feeling this is probably a locking/blocking, memory, or excessive threads. Truthfully a well planned and designed database should be able to eat this workload and not skip a beat.

Lastly, (and not knowing your level of expertise here) i would do a lot of research into indexing, query performance, table formalization, and Locking Hints

Comment: I'll be learning and using the tools you suggest. Just so I might elicit more advice from you: Any changes I make will need to be restricted to my app because it is an ad-hoc search tool designed to search any DB. As such, I cannot expect to have the luxury of modifying any DB to improve the performance of my search program. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Other than that, my program uses a 2-block TPL dataflow as shown and submits the SQL select statements as described above. Really a pretty brute-force approach. I use "using" statements to connect and query for each table field. I'm modifying my code now to submit one query for all of a table's fields to see if reducing the raw number of connect+query operations will help

Comment: @NovaSysEng maybe you also want to try in https://dba.stackexchange.com/