# TPL DataFlow not processing all messages

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I'm implementing simple data loader over HTTP, following tips from my previous question [C# .NET Parallel I/O operation (with throttling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310353/c-sharp-net-parallel-i-o-operation-with-throttling), answered by [Throttling asynchronous tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks).

I split loading and deserialization, assuming that one may be slower/faster than other. Also I want to throttle downloading, but don't want to throttle deserialization. Therefore I'm using two blocks and one buffer.

Unfortunately I'm facing problem that this pipeline sometimes processes less messages than consumed (I know from target server that I did exactly `n` requests, but I end up with less responses).

My method looks like this (no error handling):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DummyData>> LoadAsync(IEnumerable<Uri> uris)
{
    IList<DummyData> result;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<DummyData>();

        var downloader = new TransformBlock<Uri, string>(
            async u => await client.GetStringAsync(u),
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxParallelism });

        var deserializer =
            new TransformBlock<string, DummyData>(
                s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DummyData>(s),
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

        var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

        downloader.LinkTo(deserializer, linkOptions);
        deserializer.LinkTo(buffer, linkOptions);

        foreach (Uri uri in uris)
        {
            await downloader.SendAsync(uri);
        }

        downloader.Complete();
        await downloader.Completion;

        buffer.TryReceiveAll(out result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

So to be more specific, I have 100 URLs to load, but I get 90-99 responses. No error & server handled 100 requests. This happens randomly, most of the time code behaves correctly.

Comment: Your only awaiting completion of the `downloader` when it completes the message still must be deserialized and put in the buffer.

Comment: @JSteward Oh, ... I'm speechless, thank you! (I misinterpreted `PropagateCompletion` property pretty badly)

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues with your code:

1. Awaiting for the completion of the first block of the pipeline (`downloader`) instead of the last (`buffer`).
2. Using the `TryReceiveAll` method for retrieving the messages of the `buffer` block. The correct way to retrieve all messages from an unlinked block without introducing race conditions is to use the methods `OutputAvailableAsync` and `TryReceive` in a nested loop. You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714155/tpl-how-do-i-split-and-merge-the-dataflow/58751948#58751948) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541425/tpl-dataflow-propagate-completion-only-when-all-data-has-been-processed/62364286#62364286).
3. In case of timeout the `HttpClient` [throws an unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out) `TaskCanceledException`, and the TPL Dataflow blocks happens to ignore exceptions of this type. The combination of these two unfortunate realities means that by default any timeout occurrence will remain unobserved. To fix this problem you could change your code like this:

```
var downloader = new TransformBlock<Uri, string>(async url =>
{
    try
    {
        return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { throw new TimeoutException(); }
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxParallelism });
```

A fourth unrelated issue is the use of the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` option for the `deserializer` block. In the (hopefully unlikely) case that the `deserializer` is slower than the `downloader`, the `deserializer` will start queuing more and more work on the `ThreadPool`, keeping it [permanently starved](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/threadpool_starvation.md). This will not be good for the performance and the responsiveness of your application, or for the health of the system as a whole. In practice there is rarely a reason to configure a CPU-bound block with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` larger than `Environment.ProcessorCount`.