# TPL DataFlow propagate completion only when all data has been processed

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have a producer sending data to a `BufferBlock` and when all data has been read from the source, it calls `Complete()`.

<s>The default behaviour is that when the completion is called, even if the buffer still has messages, it propagates the completion down the pipeline.</s>

Is there a wait to tell a block: Propagate the completion only once your buffer is empty?

When the completion occurs, I get an exception on `Receive`: `InvalidOperationException: 'The source completed without providing data to receive.'`

I am currently using:

```
var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<string>();

var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(s =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);

    return s;
});

bufferBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    bufferBlock.Post(i.ToString());

bufferBlock.Complete();

while (!transformBlock.Completion.IsCompleted)
    Console.WriteLine(transformBlock.Receive());
```

To avoid it I am currently using:

```
while (bufferBlock.Count > 0)
    await Task.Delay(100);

bufferBlock.Complete();
```

which does not sound like a really clean solution.

Is it a race condition? I.E. The block flagging as not completed and them completing while I call receive?

I guess I could replace `!transformBlock.Completion.IsCompleted` with `block.OutputAvailableAsync` is that right?

Comment: So far I can't reproduce this behavior, could you provide a minimal example that illustrates this behavior? The only time when completion should be propagated is when the buffer empties out.

Comment: It would probably be most helpful to see the code used to send data into the pipeline, I suspect that's where the error is, but can't be sure.

Comment: Will write a console app to reproduce it and add code example here. It's simply a proucer sending X elements to the `BufferBlock` and then calling `Complete` while the other linked blocks are still processing. I get an exception stating the block was completed before the date could be processed.

Comment: @JSteward I figured out it was actually processing all the messages, it was just the message that was misleading.

Comment: To await completion await the Completion task of the last block. In this case, `await transformBlock.Completion`.

Answer (score 1):

To await completion of a pipeline, you should await the Completion task of the last block in the pipeline. In this case you should change your code to :

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    bufferBlock.Post(i.ToString());

bufferBlock.Complete();

await transformBlock.Completion;
```

This is demonstraded in the [Completing a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#completing-pipeline-activity) and [Waiting for the pipeline to finish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#waiting-for-the-pipeline-to-finish) paragraphs of [Walkthrough: Creating a Dataflow Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline)

TransformBlock has a buffer already which means anything posted to the input BufferBlock will be sent to the TransformBlock immediatelly. It would be better to use a different block for testing purposes. The walkthrough shows a nice example: One transformBlock to download page contents, another to parse them etc.

Just be careful of various .... unfortunate coding practices like creating a new HttpClient instance each time. The downloader could be changed to :

```
  var httpClient=new HttpClient();
  var downloadString = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async uri =>
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Downloading '{0}'...", uri);

     return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct way to retrieve messages from a block manually is by using the [`OutputAvailableAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.outputavailableasync) method, in combination with the [`TryReceive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.tryreceive):

```
while (await transformBlock.OutputAvailableAsync())
{
    while (transformBlock.TryReceive(out var item))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
await transformBlock.Completion; // Required to propagate exceptions
```

The properties `BufferBlock.Count`, `TransformBlock.OutputCount` etc are only suitable for monitoring and statistics. Using them for controlling the flow of the data is in most cases an indication of possible race conditions and lurking bugs.