# How to execute tasks in parallel but not more than N tasks per T seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I need to run many tasks in parallel as fast as possible. But if my program runs more than 30 tasks per 1 second, it will be blocked. How to ensure that tasks run no more than 30 per any 1-second interval?

In other words, we must prevent the new task from starting if 30 tasks were completed in the last 1-second interval.

My ugly possible solution:

```
private async Task Process(List<Task> taskList, int maxIntervalCount, int timeIntervalSeconds)
{
    var timeList = new List<DateTime>();

    var sem = new Semaphore(maxIntervalCount, maxIntervalCount);
    var tasksToRun = taskList.Select(async task =>
    {
        do
        {
            sem.WaitOne();
        }
        while (HasAllowance(timeList, maxIntervalCount, timeIntervalSeconds));

        await task;

        timeList.Add(DateTime.Now);

        sem.Release();
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasksToRun);
}

private bool HasAllowance(List<DateTime> timeList, int maxIntervalCount, int timeIntervalSeconds)
{
    return timeList.Count <= maxIntervalCount 
    || DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIntervalSeconds)) > timeList[timeList.Count - maxIntervalCount];
}
```

Comment: Actual throttling is provided by ReactiveX operators like `Window` and `Buffer`. You can use an `ActionBlock<T>` with a limited DOP and possibly an `await Task.Delay()` to ensure you don't make more than N calls/second

Comment: Whoever voted to close as "opinion-based", it's definitely not. You can argue there have been similar questions in the past, but this is *definitely* not a matter of opinion.

Comment: [This is probably a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks). One answer shows how to use a DataFlow block with a DOP of 50 to limit concurrent operations to 50. The other shows how to use a SemaphoreSlim. One could use *both* - a DOP to limit operations to no more than 30 (or less), and a SemaphoreSlim that gets reset every 1 second by a timer.

Comment: BTW in this code, the tasks are *all already running*. The code only *awaits* them to complete at a specific rate. That's not what you asked though  - that's more like *batching* incoming operations before passing them to the step that needs throttling. You can get similar behavior with a BatchBlock

Comment: Lets suppose that initially you start 30 of your tasks. At the time 0:00.5 (half a second later) all 30 tasks are still running. At the time 0:01.0 (one second later) 15 tasks have been completed and 15 are still running. Is it allowed then to start 15 more tasks? If it is, then at the interval 0:00.5 - 0:01.1 more than 30 tasks were active. If it's not, then you will be allowed to start a new task only after the completion of **all** 30 initial tasks. Which one is the desired behavior?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias if 15 tasks have been completed at the time 0:01.0 It means that we can run the next 15 tasks only after 1 second - at the time 0:02.0. Because like you said we will have more than 30 active tasks in 1-second interval.

Comment: Thanks @Palindromer for the clarification. I have wrote an answer that solves this problem elegantly by using a `SemaphoreSlim` and a `Task.Delay`, but I must wait until the question is reopened before I can post my answer.

Comment: This is a good and enough detailed question, why it was closed?

Answer (score 1):

User code should never have to control how tasks are scheduled directly. For one thing, it can't - controlling how tasks run is the job of the [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8). When user code calls `.Start()`, it simply adds a task to a threadpool queue for execution.  `await` executes already executing tasks.

The TaskScheduler samples show how to create limited concurrency schedulers, but again, there are better, high-level options.

The question's code doesn't throttle the queued tasks anyway, it limits how many of them can be awaited. They are all running already. This is similar to batching the *previous* asynchronous operation in a pipeline, allowing only a limited number of messages to pass to the next level.

**ActionBlock with delay**

The easy, out-of-the-box way would be to use an ActionBlock with a limited MaxDegreeOfParallelism, to ensure no more than N concurrent operations can run at the same time. If we know how long each operation takes, we could add a bit of delay to ensure we don't overshoot the throttle limit.

In this case, 7 concurrent workers perform 4 requests/second, for a total of 28 maximum request per second. The `BoundedCapacity` means that only up to 7 items will be stored in the input buffer before `downloader.SendAsync` blocks. This way we avoid flooding the `ActionBlock` if the operations take too long.

```
var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(
        async url => {
            await Task.Delay(250);
            var response=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            //Do something with it.
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 7, BoundedCapacity=7 }
);

//Start posting to the downloader
foreach(var item in urls)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(item);
}
downloader.Complete();
await downloader.Completion;
```

**ActionBlock with SemaphoreSlim**

Another option would be to combine this with a `SemaphoreSlim` that gets reset periodically by a timer.

```
var refreshTimer = new Timer(_=>sm.Release(30));

var downloader = new ActionBlock<string>(
        async url => {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try 
            {
                var response=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
                //Do something with it.
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, BoundedCapacity=5 }
);

//Start the timer right before we start posting 
refreshTimer.Change(1000,1000);
foreach(....)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) limited to the number of maximum tasks per interval, that is released with a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) when the interval has elapsed after launching a task. The same idea has been used [for answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825673/partition-how-to-add-a-wait-after-every-partition/65829971#65829971) a similar question (the `RateLimiter` class). Below is an implementation based on this idea, with a signature and behavior that mimics the .NET 6 [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API:

```
/// <summary>
/// Projects each element of the source sequence into a new form using an
/// asynchronous delegate, enforcing a limit on the number of concurrent
/// asynchronous operations that can start during a specified time span.
/// </summary>
public static Task<TResult[]> Parallel_ForEachAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> body,
    int maxActionsPerTimeUnit,
    TimeSpan timeUnit,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    if (maxActionsPerTimeUnit < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxActionsPerTimeUnit));
    if (timeUnit < TimeSpan.Zero || timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds > Int32.MaxValue)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeUnit));

    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(maxActionsPerTimeUnit, maxActionsPerTimeUnit);
    CancellationTokenSource cts = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    List<System.Threading.Timer> timers = new();

    async Task<Task<TResult[]>> EnumerateSourceAsync()
    {
        // This method always completes successfully.
        // Any errors are wrapped in the tasks.
        List<Task<TResult>> tasks = new();
        try
        {
            foreach (TSource item in source)
            {
                try
                {
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        tasks.Add(Task.FromCanceled<TResult>(cancellationToken));
                    // Otherwise the cancellation was caused by a task failure.
                    break;
                }

                // Launch the task
                Task<TResult> task = body(item, cts.Token).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (!t.IsCompletedSuccessfully) cts.Cancel();
                    // In case of cancellation propagate the correct token.
                    if (t.IsCanceled && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return Task.FromCanceled<TResult>(cancellationToken);
                    return t;
                }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                    TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
                tasks.Add(task);

                // Schedule the release of the semaphore using a Timer.
                System.Threading.Timer timer = new(_ => semaphore.Release());
                timer.Change(timeUnit, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
                timers.Add(timer);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { tasks.Add(Task.FromException<TResult>(ex)); }
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    return EnumerateSourceAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // Clean up
        Task.WaitAll(timers.Select(t => t.DisposeAsync().AsTask()).ToArray());
        cts.Dispose();
        semaphore.Dispose();
        return t;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap().Unwrap();
}
```

Usage example:

```
int[] results = await Parallel_ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), async n =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate some asynchronous I/O-bound operation
    return n;
}, maxActionsPerTimeUnit: 30, timeUnit: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
```

The `Parallel_ForEachAsync` method propagates asynchronously all the errors that might be thrown by the `body` delegate, in exactly the same way as the built-in `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API.

For an alternative implementation that compiles on .NET platforms older than .NET 6, and also features different options (`includeAsynchronousDuration`, `onErrorContinue` and `executeOnCapturedContext`, but lacks `cancellationToken`), see the [8th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60221401/8) of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(item in listNeedInsert)
{
    var task = TaskToRun(item);
    tasks.Add(task);

    if(tasks.Count == 100)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        tasks.Clear();
    }
}

// Wait for anything left to finish
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Notice that I rather add the task into a `List<Task>();` and after all is added, I await all in the same `List<Task>();`

What you do here:

```
 var tasks = taskList.Select(async task =>
    {
        do
        {
            sem.WaitOne();
        }
        while (timeList.Count <= maxIntervalCount 
        || DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIntervalSeconds)) > timeList[timeList.Count - maxIntervalCount]);

        await task;
```

is blocking until the task finishes it's work thus making this call:

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
```

completely redundant. Furthermore, this line `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();` is performing unnecessary blocking on the  `WhenAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Is the blocking due to some server/firewall/hardware limit or it is based on observation?**

You should try to use `BlockingCollection<Task>` or similar [thread safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) especially if the job of your tasks are I/O-bound. You can even set the capacity to 30:

```
var collection = BlockingCollection<Task>(30);
```

Then you can start 2 async method:

```
var population = Task.Factory.Start(Populate);
var processing = Task.Factory.Start(Dequeue);
await Task.WhenAll(population, processing);

Task Populate()
{
    foreach (...)
        collection.Add(...);
    collection.CompleteAdding();
}
Task Dequeue
{
    while(!collection.IsComplete)
        await collection.Take();                            //consider using TryTake()
}
```

**If the limit presists due to some true limitation** (should be very rare) change Populate() as follows:

```
var stopper = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = ....)                                          //instead of foreach
{
    if (i % 30 == 0)
    {
        if (stopper.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
            Task.Delay(1000 - stopper.ElapsedMilliseconds); //note that this race condition should be avoided in your code
        stopper.Restart();
    }
    collection.Add(...);
}
collection.CompleteAdding();
```