# Async Await with many LongRunning Parallel tasks (threads)

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel-processing, threadpool, throttling

I'm trying to launch 500 requests to a REST service simultaneously.  I wrote this extension method to help with that and it works sometimes but other times it hangs on the `WhenAll` with tasks that haven't been activated.  Can anyone help me understand this and/or show me a better way?

I've tried to do this without the `LongRunning` flag and it hangs (or takes longer than I'm willing to wait) every time and my understanding is that it was just overwhelming the thread pool.  When it does work it only takes about 4 seconds.

```
public static async Task<List<TFunc>> ForEachLongRunningAsync<TSource, TFunc>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TFunc>> func)
{
    var tasks = source.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(x), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Unwrap());
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToList();
}
```

As a troubleshooting step, I modified the method to this.  This is how I determined that the tasks aren't being activated (see below).  Again, in this case it works sometimes but hangs in others.

```
    public static async Task<List<TFunc>> ForEachLongRunningAsync<TSource, TFunc>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TFunc>> func)
    {
        var tasks = source.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(x), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Unwrap()).ToList();
        var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        while (true)
        {
            if (results.IsCompleted) break;
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        return results.Result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: By declaring a task to be long-running, you're declaring that you don't want it to use the threadpool. Long-running tasks spawn up new threads. Why do you call Unwrap?

Comment: "I'm trying to launch 500 requests to a REST service simultaneously" and does your http client allow that many concurrent requests to the same server? Will those requests timeout before they have even started? And what about limits imposed by the server?

Comment: Yes, it allows that many concurrent requests. No, they will not timeout. The limits are well beyond what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throttling asynchronous tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

If your `func` is known to be asynchronous (i.e., just invoking a REST call), then there's no need to involve the thread pool at all:

```
public static async Task<List<TFunc>> ForEachLongRunningAsync<TSource, TFunc>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TFunc>> func)
{
  var tasks = source.Select(x => func(x));
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return results.ToList();
}
```

If you do need the thread pool for some reason (i.e., if `func` may be synchronous and you want to ensure it runs in parallel in that case), then the proper tool to use is `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or `Task.Run`:

```
public static async Task<List<TFunc>> ForEachLongRunningAsync<TSource, TFunc>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TFunc>> func)
{
  var tasks = source.Select(x => Task.Run(() => func(x)));
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return results.ToList();
}
```

Note that both `LongRunning` and `AttachedToParent` are wrong to use with asynchronous code, and `StartNew` is not recommended. `LongRunning` forces new threads to be created and then almost immediately discarded, making the code far less efficient. `AttachedToParent` attempts to attach to the currently-running task which is *hopefully* nothing - if it actually *did* do something it would almost certainly interfere with the generated `async` state machine.

Answer (score -1):

- In spite of [what you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75657096/async-await-with-many-longrunning-parallel-tasks-threads#comment133509488_75657096), I suspect that you *will* run into timeouts if you try to `launch 500 requests to a REST service simultaneously`. Keep in mind that [client timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-8.0), [server-side rate limiting](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/reference/legacy/old-rate-limiting/), server-side exhaustion, and server-side timeouts are all in play.
- And I doubt that you have a business requirement to truly `launch 500 requests to a REST service simultaneously`.

Instead of running a pure `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` with 500 tasks, I suggest you [throttle](https://gaevoy.com/2019/01/27/throttling-async-task.html) with, perhaps, 5 simultaneous tasks.

And I encourage you to benchmark this change. I think you will be pleasantly surprised at the throughput you'll achieve if you constrain your `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` with just 5 simultaneous tasks.

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim( /*degreeOfParallelism:*/ 5);

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => PrintNumber(i, throttler, rnd));
            Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task PrintNumber(int number, SemaphoreSlim throttler, Random random)
        {
            using (await throttler.Throttle().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1, 5))).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class ThrottlerExt // https://gaevoy.com/2019/01/27/throttling-async-task.html, 2023-12-21
    {
        internal static async Task<IDisposable> Throttle(this SemaphoreSlim throttler)
        {
            await throttler.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new Throttler(throttler);
        }

        private class Throttler : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly SemaphoreSlim _throttler;

            public Throttler(SemaphoreSlim throttler) => _throttler = throttler;

            public void Dispose() => _throttler.Release();
        }
    }
}
```